# How does printing horizontally work in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following bit of code that I am trying to print horizontally

```
for i in range(3):
  print("pile %d: " % (i + 1)),
  print("0 ")
```

my output is

```
pile 1:
0
pile 2:
0
pile 3:
0
```

what I need is

```
pile 1: 0
pile 2: 0
pile 3: 0
```

I know that a comma is supposed to be used for this statement to keep it horizontal, but I don't know where I'm supposed to put it. I know that I could just put a 0 in the first print like

```
print("pile %d: 0" % (i + 1)),
```

but that's not what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jus add `end=" "` in the first print section.

```
for i in range(3):
  print("pile %d: " % (i + 1), end=" "),
  print("0")
```

Or you can also you

```
print(f"pile {(i + 1)}:", end=" "),
```

You can use also any special character at that `end`

Answer (score 0):

The comma is a special Python 2 (and BASIC) syntax, which can't be used outside of a print statement even in Python 2 (or BASIC).

In Python 3, use the `end` parameter:

```
for i in range(3):
  print("pile %d:" % (i + 1), end=" ")
  print("0")
```

For more details and options, see the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print